Bash addition error: invalid arithmetic operator
Here is the simple operation than i'm trying to do but it always give me error "invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ""
#! /bin/bash
num1=1
num2=2
num3=$(($num1 + $num2))
echo $num3

Does anyone have an idea ?
Best regards,

This is probably due to unprintable characters like carriage return at end of your lines! Try to delete them by sed -e 's/\r$//' -i yourscrpt.sh

Btw dollar sign is useless in arithmetical construct: num3=$(( num1 + num2 ))  will work same!

That was that, thank you very much "sed -e 's/\r$//' -i yourscrpt.sh"

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub It's not useless. Sometimes it's better to get an error if the variable does not exist than for it to silently treat an undefined variable as 0.
